# Definition of an ordinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anyone explain how to do questions a and b?

- (a) Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals. Show that if $\alpha^+=\beta^+$, then $\alpha=\beta$.
- (b) Is the above result true for sets which are not necessarily ordinals? That is, if $x$ and $y$ are sets with $x^+=y^+$, then $x=y$?
- Marginal notes: (a) So that the successor (class) function is one-one on ordinals. (b) In general, $x^+=x\cup\{x\}$.

I tried to use the successor of $a$ is $a\cup\{a\}$ and also used for any $a$ and $b$ are ordinals, then $a < b$, $b < a$ and $a = b$. But I am really lost? Can anyone help?

Comment: Regarding (b), are you familiar with the axiom of foundation? It's provable with foundation, but not without it.

Comment: For (a), it is easier to show that $\alpha<\beta$  implies $\alpha^+<\beta^+$. To see this, let $\xi\in \alpha^+$. Then $\xi\in \alpha$ or $\xi=\beta$. In either case, $\xi\in\beta^+$. This shows that $\alpha^+\subset \beta^+$, i.e. $\alpha^+\le \beta^+$. Now, if $\beta\in\alpha^+$, then $\alpha=\beta$ or $\alpha\in\beta$, both of which are contradictory. So, $\beta\not\in\alpha^+$. However, $\beta\in\beta^+$, so $\alpha^+\neq\beta^+$. Thus $\alpha^+<\beta^+$.

Comment: Part (a) follows from the fact that every ordinal $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha=\bigcup(\alpha^+)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (a), suppose that $\alpha^+=\beta^+$, but $\alpha\ne\beta$. Then either there is some $x\in\alpha\setminus\beta$, or there is some $x\in\beta\setminus\alpha$. Without loss of generality suppose that there is some $x\in\alpha\setminus\beta$. Then $x\in\alpha\subseteq\alpha^+=\beta^+$, so $x\in\beta^+=\beta\cup\{\beta\}$. But $x\notin\beta$, so $x\in\{\beta\}$, i.e., $x=\beta$. Thus, $\beta\in\alpha$.

At this point you can take advantage of the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals: $\beta\in\alpha$ means that $\beta<\alpha$, which in turn implies that $\beta^+\le\alpha<\alpha^+$ and hence that $\alpha\ne\beta$ after all.

Alternatively, you can argue that since by hypothesis $\alpha^+=\beta^+$, and $\alpha\in\alpha^+$, therefore $\alpha\in\beta^+$, meaning that either $\alpha\in\beta$, or $\alpha=\beta$ (why?). If $\alpha\in\beta$, then we have $\beta\in\alpha\in\beta$, and if $\alpha=\beta$, we have $\alpha\in\alpha$. Both of these possibilities contradict the axiom of regularity (also called foundation). Did this argument use anything special about ordinals, or would it apply equally well to arbitrary sets $x$ and $y$?

Comment: If $\alpha=\beta,$ we have the desired conclusion (or a contradiction to the assumption $\alpha\ne \beta$ if we're arguing that way).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: Yes, and I probably should have pointed that out, but I wanted to emphasize the relevance of regularity.

Answer (score 0):

We don't even require ordinality for α or β, only regularity.

As long as $α^+=α \cup \{α\}$, and $β^+=β \cup \{β\}$ we have:

Suppose $α \neq β$, then
$α \in β \cup \{β\}$ since $α^+=β^+$, and also $β \in α \cup \{α\}$ requiring both $β \in α$ and $α \in β$, which is absurd.